# Bluetooth scanner, mfi and core bluetooth

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

Im working on app where the following functionalities is possible. We have made this in android, but progress for IOS is slow.

1. User can search for Bluetooth scanners inside app.
2. User selects scanner to connect to.
3. App  listens to scanning events from selected scanner.

As far as i know, point 1 and 2 requires the use of Core Bluetooth API, is this correct? While point 3 requires the scanner to be MFI?

Have any done this before? I cant seem to find any scanners with bluetooth 4.1 and MFI.

Comment: No, it depends on the Bluetooth profile you are using. If your hardware uses a legacy Bluetooth protocol such as SPP, then it must be MFi certified and you use the external accessory framework. If it uses Bluetooth Low Energy with a GATT profile, then you do not need to be MFi certified (in fact, it isn’t eligible to be MFi certifiedj and you use Core Bluetooth

Comment: BLE(4.0) does not need MFI certified.  if scanForPeripheralsWithServices does not work, need to check  whether  the scanner is MFI certified or not. otherwise update to BLE 4.0.

Comment: Thank you both for answering, helps me a lot. But the follow up question then becomes how do i know if a scanner supports GATT Profile? is this something all units support or do i have to actively look for it in specs?